# Role instance in azure cloud is auto restarting

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have 5 role instance in azure cloud. Sometimes I see these Role instances are getting auto restarted. Can anyone help me to find out the root cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for role instances to be restarted on occasion. I assume you mean one or more instances are being continuously restarted (known as recycling), or being restarted abnormally often.

Usually if a role is recycling, it means either an unhandled exception is being thrown somewhere, or your `Run()` method is running to the end and exiting. Check your logs. (If there is not enough information consider adding trace statements to your code so you can debug it.)